# How to Control Halonix WiFi smart bulb using raspberry pi

Tags: wifi, alexa

I bought a smart bulb off amazon called Halonix WiFi bulb https://www.amazon.in/Halonix-Compatible-Amazon-Google-Assistant/dp/B07NN6SZQM?ref_=ast_sto_dp which is alexa compatible and has its own app in play store.

Is there any way i can control it using my raspberry pi without alexa or its own app?

Comment: do you have a question about a Raspberry Pi?

Comment: Yes, i want to run it using the pi

Comment: your question is about the light bulb and about its communication method ... `want to run it using the pi` does not make it a Raspberry Pi question ... possibly a small chance that it is linux question ... sending the right commands could be done by almost any device

Comment: This is a raspberry pi question because the objective of the question is to find a way to control the aforementioned smart bulb using raspberry pi, please suggest a suitable forum for the question if you still think it is irrelevant here.